# My new DNS change works from America but not Sweden

Tags: domain-name-system

Several hours ago i changed nameserver and DNS info on one of my domains at my domainregistar. When i access the domain from my home computers and when my friends access the domain they get to the old ip-adress hosting the dead site(We all live in Sweden).

But when i access the website from my mobile phone or through google.com/translate or North American proxies the website is shown like it should.

Why is this?, does it take time for change to take effect for diffrent locations/countries? I find it very strange and would like to start using my site now.

Do you think it will change or could i've been doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every DNS RR has a time-to-live value, which is set by the maintainer of the authoritative zone.  Other DNS servers will usually hold on to an RR until that time expires before retrieving a new one.

There is *no way* for a DNS server to keep track of every server and client everywhere that has ever asked for an RR and tell it that a new one is available.  None.  You have to wait for the TTL to expire.

Comment: And some dns servers and individual computers ignore the TTL and just hang on to the cache for however long they feel like.  Especially anything made by Microsoft.

Comment: That's wholly inaccurate M. Tomblin.  Ironically, one of the best known softwares that ignores TTLs was made by Netscape Communications Corporation.  It, as several others, was a WWW browser.  **No** actual DNS server software ignores TTLs.

Comment: @JdeBP: all resolvers (client libraries) ignore TTLs and don't forward TTL information to their callers, and those callers are allowed to cache as long as they want. It's not the best of ideas, but there it is. And notwithstanding your wishes, most versions of Microsoft's DNS implementation need to be forced to flush expired RRs — I've been involved with support requests caused by this.

Comment: You don't understand what you're doing when you're telling people to run `ipconfig /flushdns`, then.  These are not my wishes, kid.  The simple truth is that you aren't flushing the server at all, and the Microsoft DNS server does not ignore TTLs.  This whole "some DNS servers ignore TTLs" idea is just nonsense.  **No** DNS server does this, and the idea that any of them do is an old wives' tale, that unfortunately you've bought into by not understanding where actually the DNS server is in what you are doing, M. geekosaur.

Comment: @JdeBP: so where exactly did that claim that I told people to run `ipconfig` come from? Do you actually know the distinction between server and client?

Comment: That's rich!  I repeat, M. geekosaur, you've bought into, and are shovelling, a load of old baloney, an old wives' tale that is repeated in discussion forums but that has no actual truth behind it.  Considering that your response to my statement that **no DNS server software ignores TTLs** was to talk about "client libraries", I suggest that you ask that question of yourself before asking it of others, because it appears that _you_ don't know the distinction.  Not all client libraries ignore TTLs, either.  But I despair of having to get the explanation of _that_ through to you.

Comment: @JdeBP: you didn't answer me, you blew smoke. Again, why does my talking about the server make you bring up `ipconfig`? (This is not a side issue. If you can't distinguish DNS client from server then all your statements about DNS are suspect.)

Comment: M. geekosaur, it is _you_ who is blowing smoke here, not anyone else.  It is also _you_ who conflated client and server, as I've already explained once.  Stop putting _your_ words into other people's mouths, and stop shovelling that baloney.

Answer (score 1):

Give it ~24 hours. Different ISPs and DNS servers cache entries for different amounts of time.

(Also, this really belongs more on ServerFault than StackOverflow.)